# List records out of sequence in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sequence

I have a MySQL simple table

```
+--------+------------+
| REFNUM | TSTAMP     |
+--------+------------+
| 1      | 2018-JUN-1 |
| 2      | 2018-JUN-3 |
| 3      | 2018-JAN-1 |
| 4      | 2018-JUN-4 |
| 5      | 2018-JUN-6 |
| 6      | 2018-JAN-2 |
+--------+------------+
```

And records number 3 and 6 are out of sequence base on date.  I would like a query to return REFNUM's 3 and 6 from my table.  Based on similar questions I have constructed query:

```
SELECT REFNUM FROM
(
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY REFNUM ORDER BY REFNUM  ) AS sequenceCorrect,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY REFNUM ORDER BY TSTAMP) AS sequenceActual
  FROM queries
)
  AS yourTableSequenced
WHERE
  sequenceCorrect <> sequenceActual
ORDER BY REFNUM
```

but I always get an empty result.  Can someone explain why and how to correct?

Comment: Get rid of the `partition by` clauses and this should work...

Comment: Tstamp is a date data type?

Comment: They are _all_ out of sequence if January is the first month of year!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are partitioning by `refnum`, which appears to be unique.  The means that both values are always `1`.

```
SELECT q.*
FROM (SELECT q.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY REFNUM ) AS sequenceCorrect,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TSTAMP) AS sequenceActual
      FROM queries q
     ) q
WHERE sequenceCorrect <> sequenceActual
ORDER BY REFNUM;
```

You can also do this with a *single* window function:

```
SELECT q.*
FROM (SELECT q.*,
             MAX(TSTAMP) OVER (ORDER BY REFNUM) as MAX_TSTAMP
      FROM queries q
     ) q
WHERE MAX_TSTAMP <> TSTAMP
ORDER BY REFNUM;
```

EDIT:

If you specifically want the ones where the order is reversed, then use `lag()`:

```
SELECT q.*
FROM (SELECT q.*,
             LAG(TSTAMP) OVER (ORDER BY REFNUM) as PREV_TSTAMP
      FROM queries q
     ) q
WHERE PREV_TSTAMP > TSTAMP
ORDER BY REFNUM;
```

Comment: Both code snippets return most records, but not the ones out of order.  (I'm using an actual table of 34 records)

Comment: @TSG . . . I understand what you mean.  Having two records swapped will result in all the in-between values being out of order.  I revised the question with a version using `LAG()`, which should more narrowly find the problematic records.

Answer (score 0):

What about this simple query with a subquery (Assuming `TSTAMP` is a `DATE` column):

```
SELECT REFNUM
FROM queries AS outer_query
WHERE TSTAMP < (SELECT TSTAMP FROM queries WHERE REFNUM = outer_query.REFNUM-1);
```

Try it [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b76f5/1). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that maybe there could be gaps between the ids, by checking if the current TSTAMP is less than the previous id's TSTAMP:

```
SELECT *  FROM queries q WHERE 
    (q.TSTAMP < 
    (SELECT qq.TSTAMP FROM queries qq WHERE REFNUM = 
    (SELECT MAX(REFNUM) FROM queries WHERE REFNUM < q.REFNUM)))
```